# Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS facing issues

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

While upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS(using upgrade manager GUI), all packages were downloaded, but then while the installation of **snap gtk-common-themes**.

It has been more than 2 hours and it's still frozen. It's greyed out and I can't even copy the lines of terminal(in GUI). I haven't taken any backup also, so how should I continue with the situation?

[image]

Edit: Forced quit the GUI upgrade manager, rebooted successfully. Now it boots in 18.04, but none of the characters are visible in gnome.

[image]

Comment: Can you close the window ? If so then go to the terminal and run ```sudo dpkg --configure -a``` to complete the installation.And if that error persists , please post the error message that appears in your terminal.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi killed the window, now the terminal characters are not visible, all I can see are rectangular blocks.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi ok, so characters of xterm are still visible, on running sudo dpkg --configure -a : error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process

Comment: It's possibly a problem with **fonts-ubuntu** package after upgrade.Try installing it manually via ```sudo apt install fonts-ubuntu```

Comment: @ParsaMousavi On manual installation, it shows : [fonts-ubuntu is already the newest version]

Comment: What do you get when you run ```fc-list  | grep ubuntu -i``` ? And have you changed the default font settings before upgrading ?The default font is **Ubuntu** and looks like it's installed.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi `fc-cache -fr` then reboot did the job. Thanks for help.

Comment: So you can post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. run `fc-cache -fr` in command line
2. reboot the system